# Is “ Yours is a bond worth preserving.” grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

Scenario

> Boy: Now that I have told you the story about my difficult relationship with my father, what is your advice?
>
> Old wise man: Yours is a bond worth preserving.

I am a native English speaker. I believe “Yours is a bond worth preserving.” to be grammatically correct yet I am unable to find a rule concerning possessive pronouns where a sentence like this is spoken about.

Comment: You say " I do believe [it[ to be grammatically correct yet I do require confirmation".  Csn you give some more details.  Why do you think that it is correct?  What gives you doubt.  Why do you need confirmation.  The problem with your question is that you have phrased it as a Yes/No question.  And this doesn't provoke answers that explain Why.  So can you tell us what you are worried about with this sentence?

Comment: My apologies. I am unable to find a rule concerning possessive pronouns where a sentence like “Yours is a bond worth preserving.” is spoken about.

Comment: Yes it's correct. **Yours** is functioning as the subject of the sentence, referring back to "relationship", and is like any other pronoun.  Not sure what the confusion is here to be honest.

Comment: Would you consider "This is yours" to be grammatical? What do you see as the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Possessive pronouns can be the subject of a sentence.

Possessive pronouns come in pairs:  "my-mine", "your-yours" etc.  The first form is used as a determiner "your house", and the second form is used on its own: Yours means "your one", with the reference made clear from context.

So "Yours is a bond..." means "Your bond..." and the bond is the bond with his father.